# Flutter Xcode build failed error unable to spawn process

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, command, xcode-command-line-tools

I followed the Flutter docs to the letter doing the install etc. Downloaded the Zip and extracted to my own dev directory. I added the flutter path.

```
export PATH="/Users/me/dev/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

Tested flutter doctor

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.2.1 20D75 darwin-x64, locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/me/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (5 weeks ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin installed
    • Dart plugin version 201.9317
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin installed
    • Dart plugin version 203.6912


[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro (mobile) • 95B08A93-656C-42F9-AD8B-AF2325CFCAF2 • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)

• No issues found!


/Users/me/dev/flutter/bin/flutter
/Users/me/dev/flutter/bin/dart
```

then did the Xcode set up according to the docs.
And finally created the flutter project from the command line, and flutter run.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...

Running Xcode build...
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                         4.2s
Xcode build done.                                           48.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
   ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
   error: unable to spawn process
   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
   /usr/bin' (Permission denied) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
   warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Failed to open
   diagnostics file") (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
   error: unable to spawn process
   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
   /usr/bin' (Permission denied) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
   warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Failed to open
   diagnostics file") (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
   note: Using new build system
   note: Building targets in parallel
   note: Planning build
   note: Constructing build description
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.

Any Ideas to the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open ios folder by using Xcode and run it !

Comment: In Xcode when I open the iOS file this is the error i get.

Runner  1 issue
Error
        Runner.app/Info.plist does not exist. The Flutter "Thin Binary" build phase must run after "Copy Bundle Resources".

Runner Project 1 issue
Validate Project Settings
 Updateto recommended settings
   Runner.xcodeproj

Comment: When I perform the recommended changes that Xcode is requesting I get this error

Runner 38 issues 
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group
/Users/me/myapp/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:8:10: Double-quoted include "FlutterAppDelegate.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead

/Users/me/myapp/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:8:9: While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/me/myapp/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:8:

the rest are similar complaining about .h files.